# Html input value does not display the complete variable while populating html form

Tags: python, html, input, flask

I have the below code, I have passed the dictionary from my python Flask code to the HTML form. When i am displaying in the form of table, it is displaying the key and the values correctly. But When i try to populate the values into an HTML form, giving the input value as the value of my dictionary. It does not display the complete value of the variable. It just prints the first word. `

```
 <form>
    {% for key, value in result.items() %}
       {% for k1,v1 in value.items() %}

    <br>
    {{v1}}:<br>
     <input type="text" name={{k1}} value={{v1}} size = "50" ><br>


    {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
```

`
In the above code the value which i need to be displayed is in {{v1}}. For example, if the value is "ABC Corporation". It displays ABC. What i have noticed is that it is discarding everything after a space, or a colon or semicolon. Anybody has any clue why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need quotes around the value, otherwise the space ends the attribute.

In general, you should put quotes around *all* attribute values.

```
<input type="text" name="{{k1}}" value="{{v1}}" size = "50" ><br>
```